# Invalid parameter in WTSQueryUserToken()

Tags: c

Why am I getting an ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER 0x57 in running WTSQueryUserToken()

```
HANDLE GetCurrentUserToken(){
    HANDLE currentToken = 0, HANDLE primaryToken = 0;
    ULONG dwSessionId = 0;
    int i;
    PWTS_SESSION_INFO pSessionInfo = 0;
    DWORD dwCount = 0;
    WTSEnumerateSessions(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, 1, &pSessionInfo, &dwCount);
    for (i = 0; i < (int)dwCount; ++i){
        WTS_SESSION_INFO si = pSessionInfo[i];
        if (WTSActive == si.State){ 
            dwSessionId = si.SessionId;
            break;
        }
    }   
    WTSFreeMemory(pSessionInfo);
    BOOL bRet = WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId, currentToken); // Getting an Error in here
    if (bRet == FALSE)
        return 0;
```

Comment: [`WTSQueryUserToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsqueryusertoken) requires a `PHANDLE`, that is pointer to a `HANDLE`, as second parameter, because it fills in the correct handle on success, so you should pass in `&currentToken`. (A Windows `HANDLE` is just a typedef for `void *`, so you don't get any warnings.)

Comment: The error still persist even if i change it to PHANDLE tho

Comment: Well, since I don't know anything else about `WTSQueryUserToken`, that was the one piece of advice I had to offer.

Comment: (Also, I may not have made myself entirely clear: The type of `currentToken` must still be `HANDLE`, not `PHANDLE`, but you must make it a `PHANDLE` in the function call by passing its address like so: `WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId, &currentToken)`.)

Comment: Yeah i thought so too, tnx anyways

Comment: For what it's worth, I can reproduce that you get error 87 (0x57) with the original code, but when I make the changes I suggested, I get error 1314 ("Privilege not held") instead.

Comment: May I see your code? I may have a way with privilege not held, god i'm stuck with this project

Comment: I get the same error you got 1314